# LINQ Order By sort Problem

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a LINQ Query:

```
bikersList = (From c In ngBikersDataContext.Reg_Bikers _
              Order By c.L_Name _
              Select New Bikers() With { _
                  .BikerID = c.BikerID, _
                  .F_Name = c.F_Name, _
                  .M_Name = c.M_Name, _
                  .L_Name = c.L_Name, _
                  .MyID = c.MyID, _
                  .Site = c.Site.GetValueOrDefault, _
                  .bk_Building = c.bk_Building, _
                  .bk_City = c.bk_City, _
                  .bk_Zip = c.bk_Zip.GetValueOrDefault, _
                  .bk_Phone = c.bk_phone, _
                  .email = c.email, _
                  .DeptZone = c.DeptZone, _
                  .QuartID = c.QuartID.GetValueOrDefault, _
                  .BikerDays = c.BikerDays.GetValueOrDefault, _
                  .BikerMiles = c.BikerMiles.GetValueOrDefault, _
                  .BikerTime = c.BikerTime.GetValueOrDefault, _
                  .BKLockID = c.BKLockID.GetValueOrDefault, _
                  .bk_Start_DT = c.bk_Start_DT, _
                  .bk_End_DT = c.bk_End_DT, _
                  .bk_Quarter = c.bk_Quarter.GetValueOrDefault, _
                  .bk_Year = c.bk_Year.GetValueOrDefault, _
                  .bk_Comments = c.bk_Comments, _
                  .IsActive = c.IsActive.GetValueOrDefault _
              }).ToList()
```

This works great and sorts on `L_Name`. But I am trying to allow the user to sort the gridview themselves so I am passing in the SortExpression as a string. But I don't know how to incorperate the SortExpression into the LINQ Query.

I tried `Order By c. & SortExpression` but that did not work.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by dynamically constructing the linq expression using [System.Linq.Expressions.Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

[Here](http://www.thereforesystems.com/dynamic-sort-with-linq-to-sql/) is an example which explains the same